# Istanbul ignore next not working inside JSX and nested arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, istanbul

I'm trying to use instanbul ignore next to ignore some lines in my test coverage but it dont work inside a JSX or nested array. Anyone have an idea of what I can do?

```
          <Text
            as="span" /* istanbul ignore next */ - IT WONT WORK HERE
            variant={isMobile ? 'medParagraph' : 'smParagraph'} //im trying to ignore this line
            sx={{
              fontWeight: selected ? 'bold' : undefined,
            }}>
            {page}
          </Text>
```

---

```
  const itemList = [
    ...(siblingsEnd < count - boundaryCount - 1
      ? ['end-ellipsis']
      : count - boundaryCount > boundaryCount
      ? [count - boundaryCount]
      : []),
    /* istanbul ignore next */ - WONT WORK HERE AS WELL
    ...endPages, //im trying to ignore this line
    ...(hideNextButton ? [] : ['next']),
    ...(showLastButton ? ['last'] : []),
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to ignore the nested array placing the istanbul above the const definition.

Same with the JSX, I just placed the istanbul above the return.